# Symfony redirect to route passing url slug

Tags: symfony, redirect

I've searched this on SO previously, but it seems that the only answers given are when parameters are passed as a query string, which is not what I want.

I have a page in my Symfony 3 CRM with a route `app_litter`. There is a required URL slug called `litter_id` which needs to be passed to the route in order to determine which litter data to show, as follows:

> /litter/1

My route definiton in the routing file is:

```
app_view_litter:
    path: /litter/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Litter:view, id: null }
    requirements:
        id: \d+
```

There is a function which allows a user to add puppies to their litter, which is a form outside of this page - once the puppies are successfully saved, I want to redirect the user back to the litter in question, so I did this:

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('app_litter', array('litter_id' => $litter->getId()));
```

Where `$litter` is the object retrieved from Symfony. However, this redirects to:

> /litter?litter_id=1

Which does not work, as it expects a slug. Is it possible to use `redirectToRoute()` (or any other method) to render the route with a slug instead of a query string?

Comment: Show your route definition.

Comment: @BorisGuéry have added it to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Because your route definition is:

```
app_view_litter:
    path: /litter/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Litter:view, id: null }
    requirements:
        id: \d+
```

When using the route generator you need to provide an associated array with keys corresponding to the name of your placeholders which is in your case `id`.

Therefore, it must be:

`$this->redirectToRoute('app_litter', array('id' => $litter->getId()));`

If you want to use a slug, and there something which not only composed of digits (`\d+`), you have to either define a new route or modify the existing.

```
app_view_litter_using_slug:
    path: /litter/{slug}
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Litter:view, slug: null }
    requirements:
        id: .*
```

And you something like:

`$this->redirectToRoute('app_litter_using_slug', array('slug' => $litter->getSlug()));`

Comment: Hm ok I missed that - but even if I use `litter?id=1` it still fails because it thinks id the id is null. The error is Call to member function getBlah() on null

Comment: Why would you use litter?id=1 when your path is supposed to be litter/1 ? Could you provide the full action code

Comment: @MichaelEmerson it probably fails because it shouldn't match any valid routes, `/litter?id={id}` doesn't match `/litter/{id}` with your actual requirement.

Comment: @BorisGuéry Yes I know it fails because of this! This is why I asked the question, how to pass it as a slug in the URL!

Comment: @MichaelEmerson, edited. Though, I actually advise you to get a look in depth on how the [Routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html) component works.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you are using the wrong route? Try using `app_view_litter` instead of `app_litter`:

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('app_view_litter', array('id' => $litter->getId()));
```

Comment: No, the route is not wrong. This is the individual page, not the listing of all litters.

Comment: as Boris pointed you should use the `id` as parameter and looking at your route definition the route name should be `app_view_litter`. I will update the answer.

Comment: This still doesn't work. The point I'm trying to get across is that it passes it back as a query string and not a slug in the URL.

Comment: that sounds like a route is matching the call where that parameter is not defined. So if you generate the url with the call from above you get redirected to `/litter?id={id}` ? Are there other routes configured for the `litter` term?